# Exract text between HTML tags and count them

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

so lets say I have written an article with many tags like `[code]this is a code[/code]`, and I would know how many `code` tags are in the article and what is the text inside.

I tried `preg_matches` and `preg_replaces`, but nothing has worked so far.  What would be the appropriate way to do it?

Comment: Is `/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/` what you're looking for? (May want to add multi-line flag as well, fyi)

Comment: @Brad Christie why you didn't post it as an answer ?

Comment: @hsz: I figured by the time I posted it there would have been several answers already posted (just given simplicity and time of post). If there were dups I can delete a comment easier than a post. ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

Comment: `[code]` is a BBCode tag and not an HTML tag. Please clarify what you are after: `[code]` or `<code>`

Comment: inside [ code][ /code] tags there is php,java,c++ code text

Comment: @fxuser I didnt ask what's inside. I asked if you are parsing BBCode or HTML. Your question title asks for getting test from an HTML tag, while you are showing BBCode tags.

Comment: its BBCode tag, i asked to get whatever is inside and whatever is in the attribute "style"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pattern = '/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/s';

preg_match_all($pattern, $code, $matches);

echo count($matches)."\n";

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: +1 But you need to add the `'s'` single line modifier (and the `'i'` modifier would be a good idea too) . i.e. `'/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/is'`

Comment: input:
[code]
echo 'test';
[/code]

[code]
echo '2nd code text';
[/code]
Output:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [code]

echo 'test';

[/code]
            [1] => [code]

echo '2nd code text';

[/code]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 

echo 'test';


            [1] => 

echo '2nd code text';


        )

)
it seems to work... now i would also like to get the "style" of the code tag, like [code style=php]php code example[/code]
how can ia lso get the style=.*? text ?

Thanks

Comment: $pattern = '/\[code style=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/code\]/is';

preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches);

//get the code language

    ?><pre><?php print_r($matches[1]); ?></pre><?php
   
//get each bbcode tag text

    ?><pre><?php print_r($matches[2]); ?></pre><?php

this is the answer, thanks everyone!

Comment: If the CODE tag can have an attribute, change the regex to this: `'/\[code[^[\]]*\](.*?)\[\/code\]/is'`

Answer (score 0):

This should be interesting for your:

```
/\[code\]([^]]+)\[\/code\]/
```

You need to use a match_all to get all the values.
BTW there must be some flaw with code like this :

```
[code]blabla [code]bleh bleh[/code][/code]
```

Since regex cannot parse with multiple levels of depth. At least when the depth is unknown.

**Edit**

The `/\[code\](.*)\[\/code\]/` can be useful too, but will not catch the inner block. The first one does match only the inner one.

Comment: Hummm yes... forget the first one.